# First fetching data is successfull, second fetching not

Tags: reactjs

I want to fetch data with useEffect. With the first function, I get event details and with the second function, I get questions, which are related to the event (by ID). Fetching data for the event is successful, but second fetching data for the questions is not successful (sometimes is successful). Why fetching data once is successful, but the second time is not successful?

The output of console log:

```
Quiz.js:23 {active: true, _id: "6012eafe7813901034e77fb3", nameOfEvent: "Udalost 3", creatorId: "5fd23fb7b1a3a005cc82225d", participants: Array(0), …}

Quiz.js:45 {}

Quiz.js:23 {active: true, _id: "6012eafe7813901034e77fb3", nameOfEvent: "Udalost 3", creatorId: "5fd23fb7b1a3a005cc82225d", participants: Array(0), …}active: truecodeEvent: "udalost1"createdAt: "2021-01-28T16:49:02.374Z"creatorId: "5fd23fb7b1a3a005cc82225d"nameOfEvent: "Udalost 3"participants: []updatedAt: "2021-02-01T16:52:45.471Z"__v: 0_id: "6012eafe7813901034e77fb3"__proto__: Object

Quiz.js:45 {}
```

File Quiz.js

```
const Quiz = () => {
    const dataForQuiz = getUserDataToQuiz();
    const [eventValues, setEventValues] = useState({});
    const [questionBankOfEvent, setQuestionBankOfEvent] = useState({});

    const initDataToEvent = () => {
        getEventByEventCode(dataForQuiz.codeEvent).then(data => {
            if (!data.error) {
                setEventValues(data);
            }
            else {
                console.log(data.error);
            }
        })
    }

    console.log(eventValues);
    
    const initQuestionsForQuiz = () => {
        if (eventValues) {
            getQuestionsToEvent(eventValues._id).then((data) => {
                if (!data.error) {
                    setQuestionBankOfEvent(data);
                }
                else {
                    console.log(data.error);
                }
            })
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        initDataToEvent();
        if(eventValues){
           initQuestionsForQuiz(); 
        }
    }, []);

    console.log(questionBankOfEvent);

    const formQuiz = () => {
        return(
            <>
                <h1>Quiz</h1>
            </>
        );
    }

    return (
        <>
            {formQuiz()}
        </>
        
    );
}

export default Quiz;
```

Comment: You're logging outside the `then` of the promise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the first render of your component, you execute

```
initDataToEvent();
if(eventValues){
   initQuestionsForQuiz(); 
}
```

`initDataToEvent` is supposed to update eventValues. So you expect `initQuestionsForQuiz` to be executed.
But, by the time `if(eventValues)` is evaluated, `setEventValues` has been fired, but the `eventValues` state has not been modified yet.
Hence, if you modify your code to:

```
useEffect(() => {
    initDataToEvent();
    console.log(eventValues);
    if(eventValues){
       initQuestionsForQuiz(); 
    }
}, []);
```

You would observe `eventValues` to be empty.

In React, it is best practice to split events and logic. In your case, you want `initQuestionsForQuiz` to be run when `eventValues` has been updated and not empty. Modifying your code to:

```
useEffect(() => {
    initDataToEvent();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    if(eventValues){
       initQuestionsForQuiz(); 
    }
}, [eventValues]);
```

should make it work. What this code does is that the function given as argument to the seconde `useEffect` will be run every time `eventValues` is modified.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, due to the fact that both are in the same useEffect, since react doesn´t update useState instantly. I would separate them in two different useEffect, being:

```js
 useEffect(() => {
        initDataToEvent();
    }, []);
   
   useEffect(() => {
         if(eventValues){
           initQuestionsForQuiz(); 
        }
    }, [eventValues]);
```